# Upgrade to new version

Tags: upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I have the version 14.04.02 (Desktop) and want to upgrade to 14.10, but when running the command:

```
do-release-upgrade
```

Me warns that has no new version available, what should I do?

Comment: Just to be sure, you are using Ubuntu Server? Just to know whether you need a GUI or CLI answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're using LTS version and you're trying to upgrade to a non-LTS version of Ubuntu. Check:

```
cat /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades | grep -i prompt
```

it should print like:

```
# Default prompting behavior, valid options:
Prompt=lts
```

That means it prompted to upgrade to LTS versions but not the Development ones. If you want to upgrade to Development version of Ubuntu:

```
sudo nano /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
```

Then substitute:

```
Prompt=lts
```

to

```
Prompt=normal
```

Then save and exit. Run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo do-release-upgrade -c -d
```

Comment: I figured there was a l33t/config file way of doing this, didn't know it though! Glad you posted this answer, will definitely remember this for the future.

Answer (score 1):

14.04 is a Long term support (LTS). By default it will just upgrade to the next LTS release (which will be 16.04). To upgrade to a non-LTS release, you have to open the software update properties. On the tab with the notification settings there is a drop down selection at the bottom. Set it to any release, then it should find 14.10. Also since you are using a desktop, I suggest you use the `update-manager` GUI instead of the `do-release-upgrade` CLI application.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a setting that's automatically set if you install an LTS release fresh, instead of upgrading to it.

To change this, simply open up the Unity dash (Ubuntu logo in the upper-left-hand corner), and search for `Software`.

That should bring up a list of applications like this (different icons of course, I'm using the Numix Circle icon theme. The text will be the same):

[image]

Select the icon titled **Software & Updates**.

This will open up a window that looks something like this:

[image]

Then, you'll want to click the **Updates** tab:

[image]

Finally, change the **Notify me of a new Ubuntu version** option to be *For any new version*:

[image]

That's it! Now you can now upgrade via the Software Updater GUI or via `do-release-upgrade`!